# Create custom filter for beautify js with git

Tags: javascript, git

I would like to set a custom filter in Git, so that js files are beautified automatically. I tried creating a pre-commit hook, that runs jshint and js-beautify. This is the script I have created:

```
#!/bin/sh

files=$(git diff --cached --name-only --diff-filter=ACM | grep ".js$")
if [ "$files" = "" ]; then 
    exit 0 
fi

pass=true

echo "Javascript validation with JSHint:"

for file in ${files}; do

    result=$(jshint ${file} | egrep "error")

    if [ "$result" != "" ]; then
        echo "JSHint error: ${file}"
        echo "$(jshint ${file})"
        pass=false
    else
        echo "JSHint ok: ${file}"
        beautify=$(js-beautify ${file} -r -P --config .beautifyrc)
    fi
done

echo "Validation complete"

if ! $pass; then
    echo "Aborting commit."
    exit 1
else
    echo "Commit ok."
    exit 0
fi
```

Doing this way, files are commited, but changes made by js-beautify are not included in commit, and file changes are pending (so I would need making a second commit). I have been reading about setting a filter, but I don´t know how can a I run a custom shell script. I woulkd like setting this filter:

```
*.js js-beautify ${file} -r -P --config .beautifyrc
```

Thanks a lot, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run `git add` on the files that you change so that they are recorded. The files that you have modified are only changed in the working copy; they aren't changed on the index, which is what Git uses when creating a commit.

Note that this approach fails with partial git adds (where you are staging part of a file to be committed rather than the whole file).

Comment: To add on top, use a task runner like Grunt or Gulp and run your beautifier with it manually before you commit. I would also recommend looking into ESLint.

Comment: Thanks AlBlue, it seems it is a solution that works.

Comment: zamber, this solution is automatic, once configured, nobody from my team have to run beautify. I would do it in that way, but I want the solution more simple.